# How to specify FTP server when using FtpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I could see that he had to use FTP to write to, or delete or download a file on a Linux server:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

However I do not understand is how we identify the server to use. Also, I can not not understand is when specifies no server name, address.

So if someone could help me a little better now please understand.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please don't ask us to explain code on another site. If their code doesn't work then contact them. This site is for when *your* code doesn't work, and you should include *your* code in the question and identify exactly what part is failing and what results you expect

Comment: i don't ask you question about code, I especially asked for explanations on the functioning between the FTPr and linux server connection.

Comment: Then your question is *too broad*, where is your attempt? Do you want us to write you a book on the subject?

Comment: I just want to have explanation on how we identify on a linux server in C #? with some other post on StackOverflow I have seen that it is necessary to use FTP. However I do not understand how we identify a linux server. I don't understand how the ftp will connect to a linux server if we give him no information like name of server, user, password .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `FtpWebRequest`, you use URL to both specify the file to operate with and the server.

So if you want download a file `/path/file.ext` from FTP server `example.com`, you use a URL like:

```
ftp://example.com/path/file.ext
```

You can even include a username and password:

```
ftp://user:password@example.com/path/file.ext
```

(or you can use `FtpWebRequest.Credentials` property).

---

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://example.com/path/file.ext");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
```

---

See also [Upload and download a binary file to/from FTP server in C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44606028/850848).

Comment: Tank you. But with the second possibilitie, where are you specify the username and password ? in the same way as the first solution ?

Comment: i'm sorry, it was a misunderstanding, i have done some recherche about FtpWebRequest.Credentials and i have understood. Thank you so much for you helped now i can continu my program, have a nice day.