# Cant Pass Hebrew in text file with FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, .net-4.0, hebrew

I have a simple code that pass a text file to a FTP Server, the Text File is a simple Text "ANSI", Format - Windows-1255, with Hebrew inside.

When i Pass The File to the FTP Server And Download the file, the Hebrew character is turning to question mark (?), the file keeps its format ("ANSI", Format - Windows-1255).

Why is my Hebrew turning to question mark? (I'm working with .net4)

Here is My code

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpAddress + fileName);

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filePath);

byte[] fileContents = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255).GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

Thank You

Comment: Why does the encoding matter here? Why not just File.ReadAllBytes() and upload that for an exact binary copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the encoding of your file isn't 1255.

Try to open the file with encoding UTF-8 and recheck the result.

```
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
```

Or you can use a method [Upload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx) available in `WebClient`, so you even don't touch the file.

```
// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(ftpAddress + fileName, filePath);
```

Comment: +1 - Though I just want to clarify that it's not `FtpWebRequest` vs. `WebClient`. Both can transfer the file as is (binary transfer) and vice versa (actually `WebClient` uses `FtpWebRequest` internally). It's just that OP's code modified the file (and incorrectly), while the `WebClient` code in this answer transfers the file intact. See also [Upload and download a binary file to/from FTP server in C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44606028/850848).