# "Socket read operation has timed out" exception with SSH.NET when connecting to FTP port 21

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, sftp, ssh.net

I got the exception below when the client tries to connect to FTP server:

> Socket read operation has timed out after 30000 milliseconds.
>
> Source = "Renci.SshNet"
>
> at Renci.SshNet.Abstractions.SocketAbstraction.Read(Socket socket, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at Renci.SshNet.Session.SocketReadLine(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
>   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
>   at SftpClient.ReadAllBytesAsync() in C:\SftpClient\SftpClient.cs:line 42

Code below:

```
using (Renci.SshNet.SftpClient sftp = new Renci.SshNet.SftpClient(server,
                                                    21,
                                                    Username,
                                                    Password))                      
    sftp.Connect();  //exception here
    content = sftp.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);    
    sftp.Disconnect();                      
}
```

SSH.NET version: 2016.1.0

However, it connects via telnet like below via command prompt:

```
telnet server_ip_address 21
220 (SFTPPlus_3.15.0) Welcome to the FTP/FTPS Service.
```

A staff on server side sends me public certificates, which I installed on my Windows 10.

Any idea?

---

**Solution**:

Use this one: [github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP](http://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSH.NET is SSH/SFTP client (port 22).

You cannot use it to connect to an FTP server (port 21). FTP and SFTP are two completely different protocols.

For FTP, you can use:

- [`FtpWebRequest` .NET framework class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest) – see [Upload and download a file to/from FTP server in C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44606028/850848)
- or some 3rd party FTP implementation – like *my* [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) or [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP).

Answer (score -1):

FTP and SFTP are two completely different protocols.

For **FTP server** (**Port 21**), You can use the below code are:-

> Example : Upload files using FtpWebRequest

```
string filename = "ftp://" + ip + "//" + "HA11062020CJEIC.pdf";
FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(filename);
ftpReq.UsePassive = false;
ftpReq.UseBinary = true;
ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\*****\*****\FTP Schedular\HA11062020CJEIC.pdf";
byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFile);  //Get local pc file

//var webClient = new WebClient();  //Get file from URL
//byte[] b = webClient.DownloadData(sourceFile); 

ftpReq.ContentLength = b.Length;
using (Stream s = ftpReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
}

FtpWebResponse ftpResp = (FtpWebResponse)ftpReq.GetResponse();

if (ftpResp != null)
{
    string MessageBox = (ftpResp.StatusDescription);
}
```

Comment: The `ftpReq.UsePassive = false` is usually a bad choice. For most purposes, stick with the default `true`. + Also `ReadAllBytes` is quite inefficient solution (and the question is about download rather than upload anyway). For better approaches to both upload and download, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44606028/850848 + Setting `ftpReq.ContentLength` has no effect.

Comment: I known **ftpReq.UsePassive = false** is usually a bad choice. In this case i used **ftpReq.UsePassive = false** because my FTP Connection Modes is in Active mode.