# C# FTP with FtpWebRequest upload fails with "534 Policy requires SSL"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ftp, ftpwebrequest

When I try to upload files to an SFTP server it shows an error.

Here is my code:

```
string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(uploadingFile);

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(HostAddress+ "/test1");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserId, Password);

StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@uploadingFile);
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
filesize = ConvertBytesToMegabytes(request.ContentLength);
Console.WriteLine("hello,{0}", filesize);
// Console.WriteLine("hellosss,{0}", request.ContentLength);
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream(); 
Console.WriteLine("here,{0}", requestStream);

requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
filesizedownloaded = ConvertBytesToMegabytes(requestStream.Length);
Console.WriteLine("hellosss,{0}", filesizedownloaded);
worker.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(filesizedownloaded) / filesize) * 100));

requestStream.Close();
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
FilesDetails.SelectedFileContent = "";
Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);
MessageBox.Show("File Uploaded!", " File");
response.Close();
```

I get an exception at `Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();`

The error is:

> Remote server returned an error: (534) 534 Policy requires SSL"

Answer (score 1):

Your server requires an encrypted connection.

To enable the encrypted connection, set [`FtpWebRequest.EnableSsl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.enablessl):

```
request.EnableSsl = true;
```

---

Your code has other problems and it's unnecessarily complicated.

For a clean FTP code for C#, see [Upload and download a file to/from FTP server in C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44606028/850848).